# Print odd & even number using Multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn Multi threading and for practice, I am trying to print odd & even number using two thread. I have created an object which will act as a lock for the both the threads. When I try to execute it throws `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`.

```
class EVENODDimpl implements Runnable {
    int num;
    int temp = 0;
    Object lock = new Object();

    public EVENODDimpl( int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                while(temp<num) {
                    temp++;
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"   "+temp);
                    this.notify();
                    this.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Main Method:

```
public class EVENODD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10;
        EVENODDimpl ei = new EVENODDimpl(i);
        Thread t1 = new Thread( ei,"EvenThread");
        Thread t2 = new Thread( ei,"OddThread");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are synchronizing on an object but then calling `notify` and `wait` on a different one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `wait` and `notify` on `this`, but you should `wait` and `notify` on `lock` because you synchronize on `lock`, you can't `wait` and `notify` on other object than the one on which you're synchronizing, working version:

```
class EVENODDimpl implements Runnable {
    int num;
    int temp = 0;
    Object lock = new Object();

    public EVENODDimpl( int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                while(temp<num) {
                    temp++;
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"   "+temp);
                    lock.notify();
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As it said from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

This means that your methods `notify` and `wait` should own monitor. Or in other words the object that is calling these method must be synchronized. Your `this` object is not synchronized. That's why you get this exception. Call this method from `lock` object in your case.

Your logic is still wrong but it is up to you to explore that.

Comment: I have corrected and change the lock. I am able to print the odd & even number. I am not sure what do you mean by my logic is wrong.If there is something can you please point out.

Comment: by synchronizing on the whole method you don't getting desired concurent or parallel execution. that's make no sense in the whole idea of that. maybe you need some more intersting tasks. try to get the problems of that and how you can approach that and so on. It is not topic on the question though.

Comment: totally agree with you. I am trying to learn multi threading so solving question which I found online, I am not able to find practice questions for the same. Thanks for the help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` Exception occur because you are using notify method on the object `this.notify()` but that Object is not synchronized.
Replace `synchronized (lock)` with this:  `synchronized (this)`